# How to get the text to verify for editText in calabash Android?

Tags: automated-testing, calabash

I am new to Calabash and I am looking for a solution...
 The test case says:
 I have to verify the text on txt_email
 Below are the properties of txt_email and I have to verify that the txt_email value is cuong24@yahoo.com.

```
{
                       "id" => "txt_email",
                  "enabled" => true,
       "contentDescription" => nil,
                    "class" => "android.widget.EditText",
                    "text"  => "cuong24@yahoo.com",
                     "rect" => {
           "center_y" => 342.5,
           "center_x" => 1059.0,
             "height" => 72,
                  "y" => 378,
              "width" => 168,
                  "x" => 975
       },
              "description" => "android.widget.EditText{......}"
   },
```

I have used a custom step :

```
When /^I am verify for editText of email$/ do
  performAction('assert_view_property', "txt_email", "text", "cuong24@yahoo.com")
end
```

but its not working...

Thanks,
Cuong Nguyen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The possible solution is below.

```
Then /^I verify text in email field$/ do
  expected_text = "cuong24@yahoo.com"
  actual_text = query("EditText id:'txt_email'", :text).first
  unless expected_text == actual_text
    fail "Text in email field is incorrect. Expected '#{expected_text}', but got '#{actual_text}'."
  end
end
```

---

It can be parametrized as well, for instance:

```
Then /^email should be ".*"$/ do |expected_email|
  actual_email = query("EditText id:'txt_email'", :text).first
  unless expected_email == actual_email
    fail "Text in email field is incorrect. Expected '#{expected_text}', but got '#{actual_text}'."
  end
end
```